# i want to run multiple "or" function in python, but cant figure out how to do it

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program like this
I want to detect if there is abusive comment in any of the comment
please tell if this is correct way to write a program

```
c1=input("please enter your comment")

if "click here" or "buy now" or "link" in c1:
    print("this is spam")

else:
    print("thank you for your feedback")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the author of the question wrote was like this:

```
if ("click here") or ("buy now") or ("link" in c1):
     do something
```

Therefore the code looks if "click here" or "buy now" is truthy after that it looks if "link" is part of c1. As the string are evaluated as True, the condition will be always true.

To find the best solution I suggest to go to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value) mentioned inside the comments.

Perhaps you can use more parenthesis:

```
 if ("click here" in c1) or ("buy now" in c1) or ("link" in c1):
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution:

```
c1=input("please enter your comment")

restricted_phrases = ["click here", "buy now", "link"]

spam = False 
for p in restricted_phrases:
        if c1.find(p) != -1:
                spam = True
                break
 
if spam: print("this is spam")
else: print("thank you for your feedback")
```

Comment: `c1.find(p) != -1:` no. Don't use `str.find` use the `in` operator

Comment: it was really helpful thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

No,You are doing wrong.

You can to do it like this:

```
c1=input("please enter your comment")

if ("click here" in c1) or ("buy now" in c1) or ("link" in c1):
    print("this is spam")

else:
    print("thank you for your feedback")
```